# .htaccess not working on Xampp localhost server

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, localhost

My `.htaccess` file is not working on Xampp localhost server. I tried lot of methods on Stack Overflow but I still couldn't get it to work. What should I do?

I'm hosting on Godaddy and it's working perfectly online but not working on Xampp localhost.

Answer (score 2):

**Found the problem!**

I added `-MultiViews` to .htaccess file when I upload it to godaddy server, otherwise it wouldn't work on godaddy.. All I had to do was change `-MultiViews` to `+MultiViews`

**Before**

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes
```

**After**

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks +MultiViews -Indexes
```

Comment: OMG this was a life saver!